# readOGR: all features NULL

Tags: r, ogr, rgdal

Getting an error when trying to load a shapefile via readOGR. readOGR works fine on my personal computer (mac) but I am running into issues on my work computer (windows).

When loading a shapefile using the typical syntax, I get the following error:

```
    Warning in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  :
      ogrInfo: all features NULL
    Error in readOGR(dsn = ".", "shp_example")  : no features found
```

For something reproducible, when I run the following code from the example from help(readOGR):

```
    library(rgdal)

    ogrDrivers()
    dsn <- system.file("vectors", package = "rgdal")[1]
    ogrListLayers(dsn)
    ogrInfo(dsn)
```

I get the following warning after "ogrInfo(dsn)", telling me that all features are null. Note that I only get this error on my work computer; this error does not occur on my personal computer:

```
    Warning in ogrInfo(dsn) : ogrInfo: all features NULL
```

Any ideas as to what is going on?

Comment: I have both OS (mac and windows) and I haven't problems running the code exposed. Which version of GDAL is installed on your windows PC? Did you try reinstalling `rgdal`?

Comment: What's the output of `ogrDrivers()` and `ogrListLayers(...)` for this data? What version of R, sp, and rgdal is it?

Comment: @aldo_tapia
I tried reinstalling rgdal but am running into the same problem.

Trying to check which version of GDAL is installed - how do I check this?

Comment: @Spacedman 
R version: 3.4.1
sp version: 1.2-5
rgdal version: 1.2-8
///
ogrDrivers() gives a matrix with 55 rows, with "name", "long_name", "write" (mix of TRUE and FALSE), "copy" (mostly FALSE), and "isVector" (all TRUE)
///
ogrListLayers(...) gives:
        Error: '...' used in an incorrect context
///
ogrListLayers("C:/Users/shpFldr") gives:

[1] "buildings"
attr(,"driver")
[1] "ESRI Shapefile"
attr(,"nlayers")
[1] 1

Comment: @RobMarty in cmd windows run `gdalinfo --version`

Comment: @aldo_tapia 
Thanks -- here's what it says when I run that:

`'gdalinfo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I'm guessing this means something might be missing in GDAL on the PC?

Comment: @RobMarty yes, mean that you don't have installed GDAL in you PC. [Download it](http://www.gdal.org/usergroup0.html) or install another software that uses it as dependency, as QGIS for example

Comment: @aldo_tapia Thanks for that - I downloaded GDAL and everything is working now!

Comment: @RobMarty great! Good to know that