# rgdal::readOGR - no features found

Tags: r, rgdal

Working in R Studio I'm executing the lines:

```
setwd("D:/Perfil_IBGE/4. IBGE") 
pasta = "1. Shapefiles Brasil" 
shapefile_brasil = "BRUFE250GC_SIR" 
shp <- rgdal::readOGR(dsn = pasta, layer = shapefile_brasil)
```

the result is: "no features found"

I work with Windows 10 and I checked about GDAL in my machine and I have this library installed.

What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/asking) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I see 2 possible sources of error: special characters or layer name. What happen if you remove points and spaces in your names like `D:/Perfil_IBGE/4_IBGE/1_Shapefiles_Brasil` and what does the output of the command

Comment: and what does output the command `ogrListLayers(".")` (in the directory where you have the shapefile) ?

Comment: what does ogrInfo(pasta) return?  This is similar: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/249781/readogr-all-features-null  I'd try sf as well, but more help really needs access to this data set, is it publically available?